# Removing water from a tire

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, everyday-life, fluid-statics

As a kid, we used to play with used tires on my grandma's farm.

When there was water inside a tire, we could never remove it: the water would just roll to the other side when we were turning the tire around.

Being curious, we drove a metal spike through the diameter of a tire, so essentially we had 'tire on a stick' we could flip.

Even though we were able to flip a tire upside down quickly, on a single axis, gravity never had a chance.. water inside would still run to the other side along the inside wall.

Anyone has an idea why?

Edit: A quick Photoshop to illustrate
[image: Tire with a spike through it]

Comment: If you drove a spike through it, don't you have a hole that you can use to drain the water?

Comment: sorry, not super clear: the spike was horizontal, like meat on a rotation bbq. my question is really about why flipping the tire, along the horizontal axis doesn't allow the water to fall through gravity, but it runs along the edges, even at a fairly fast speed.

Comment: Rotate the tire 90 degrees and your spike (and thus your hole) is vertical....

Comment: sure, but the question is about the water's behavior; I know that a hole in the tire will allow it to leak out

Comment: Right. My point is that why bother spinning fast when you have a hole in it? That part just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I added a quick picture to illustrate the situation, the tire is rotated around the spike. A Google search shows people asking how to remove water from tires and there are also youtube videos about it. What I'm after is to understand what makes the water run along the inner walls rather than fall out. I guess that at low speed it will run along the internal walls, and at high speed it will be pushed against the inner wall and stay inside the tire, but I'd be curious to understand it well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you answered your own question about high speeds - it would clearly flow along the inside of the tire if you spun the tire fast.

For slow speeds, think about the limiting case of *very* slow speeds. As you gradually leveled the tire, the water would flow based on Bernoulli's principle - which in this case just means searching for the lowest point. The water has no trouble doing this around the holes you made, so no water leaks out.

So presumably, there is some middle ground between these two, where the water can leak out through those holes you made. This would depend sensitively on the geometry of the tire, and you would have to work it out. For empty holes, I suspect you could find a particular angular velocity at which the water would empty through the holes.

BUT since there is a rod through the holes, you have the additional problem of the surface tension of the water preventing leakage through the holes. Maybe that's too much "real life" for this question, but I think that's the real reason you never got leakage - you plugged the holes!

If you want to consider empty holes, you are basically doing what's called a "banking" problem, and would depend on the angle of the sides of the tire. I guess we can talk about that, but it's very specific and the answer would be the same: There is a very small range of angular speeds at which you can spin the tire and get leakage through some holes, and it's extremely difficult to produce this angular speed in real life.